# Why do my elements get deleted after changing their innerText?

Tags: javascript

So on the click of a button, I run some basic maths and change the innerText of some elements, which I know actually refer to the HTML elements. I also don't get any errors what so ever in the console

JS code:

```
buypaper.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (pcls >= papercost) {
            earn(-papercost);
            papercost += (papercost / 100) * 30;
            papercost = Math.floor(papercost);
            paper += 1;
            ppc += 20;
            papercounttext.innerText = `you have ${numberWithCommas(paper)} sheets of paper`; // where i suspect the error is happening
            papercosttext.innerText = `price of next sheet of paper: ${numberWithCommas(papercost)} pencils`;
            ppctext.innerText = `you make ${numberWithCommas(ppc)} pencils/click`;
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: My guess.... buypaper is a submit button `buypaper.addEventListener("click", function(evt) { evt.preventDefault();`

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Comment: a code style tip. Use camelCase so your variables are able to be read easier. buyPaper, paperCost paperCountText, etc

Comment: Update: I have narrowed the error down to ```papercounttext.innerText = `you have ${numberWithCommas(paper)} sheets of paper`;```